# Phenol's resonance structure doesn't match NMR

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, resonance

I've asked a question before and quickly realised that the resonance/mesometric effects played a large role in determining the C-13 NMR spectrum of phenol, shown below.

[image]

This is the resonance structure of phenol:

[image]

But given this, I would have expected the carbons at $b$ to be more shifted than the ones at $d$. This is because although they both have partial negative charges, the inductive effect of the hydroxy group on $a$ should make $b$ more deshielded than $d$.

Why is this?

Comment: now it seems that you're accounting *only* for the mesomeric effect and not the induction. Consider the combined effects, especially with regard to how the positive charge distributes.

Comment: @Andrew If I account for the inductive effect, shouldn't that would mean that d should be more shielded than b? This is because b is closer to the positive oxygen which will be withdrawing electron density. So why isn't this the case?

Comment: I think the answer is gonna be more complicated than just inductive/resonance effects --- 13C shifts are not very straightforward, it's tempting to think of them like we do 1H shifts, but the underlying reasons for the chemical shifts are rather different